# Custom Transformation in Json objevct with Notepad++

Tags: json, regex, notepad++

Hi I need a help to transform below json objects in Notepad++:

1. Input: `[{ "id": "offerId": 1 },{ "id": "offerId": 25 }]`

   Ouput: `[{ "id":1, "offerId": 1 },{ "id":25, "offerId": 25 }]`

   Basically add same value as `offerId` in `id` and add comma after that. I tried something like `Find: "id":[^\n]+\n  "offerId"\: (\d+)   Replace: "id": \10,\n  "offerId": \10` but its not working.
2. Input: `[{ "localOfferId": 980568, "id": { "$numberLong": "4102980568" } },{ "localOfferId": 981161, "id": { "$numberLong": "4001981161" } }]`

   Output : `[{ "offerId": 980568, "id":"4102980568" },{ "offerId": 981161, "id": "4001981161" }]`

   Basically replacing `localOfferId` with `offerId` (that I am able to do) and removing `$numberLong` from `id` field

Comment: For 1: `("id"):\s*("offerId"):\s(\d+)` replacement `$1: $3, $2: $3`. For 2: `"localOfferId":\s(\d+),\s*("id"):\s*{\s*"\$numberLong":\s*("\d+")\s*\}` replacement `"offerId": $1, $2: $3`

Comment: Why notepad++? Just use some JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1:

```
Find: ("id":)([\n\s]*"offerId": )(\d+)
Replace: $1 $3,$2$3
```

For 2:

```
Find: "localOfferId"(: \d+,[\n\s]*"id":).*?[\s\n]*.*?("\d+")
Replace: "offerId"$1 $2
```

These will find and replace and keep the source format (space, tab, newline) in `$2` group

Comment: `[\n\s]` doesn't make sense, `\n` is included in `\s`. Moreover this is the same answer provided by @ctwheels.